# MongoDB/Mongoose batch update race conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, race-condition

Say I have the following method:

```
export async function markItemsPending (transaction: string, items: string[]) {
  const result = await Inventory.update({
    _id: {$in: items},
    state: InventoryState.Available
  }, {
    state: InventoryState.Pending,
    transaction: transaction
  }, {
    multi: true
  });
  return result.n;
}
```

And say that this method gets called simultaneously on two different threads with different transaction ids (say `Tx1` and `Tx2`) but the same items (all of which are `Available` prior to these calls). Which of the following things can happen?

1. All items are set to `Pending` with the same transaction. One call returns `items.length` while the other returns `0`
2. All items are set to `Pending`. Some have `transaction` set to `Tx1` and some have `transaction` set to `Tx2`. The return values of the two function calls sum to exactly `items.length`
3. All items are set to `Pending`. Some have `transaction` set to `Tx1` and some have `transaction` set to `Tx2`. The return values of the two function calls sum to a number **greater than** `items.length`, indicating that some items have been updated by both method calls.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're asking a hypothetical question (e.g. which of the scenario is likely to occur) or are you seeing an actual race condition symptoms based on the code you posted?

Comment: It is a hypothetical question. I haven't observed any race condition symptoms, but I would like to know for sure whether or not it is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure how mongoose handles "transactions", but MongoDB with WiredTiger is atomic on the document level. If there are two updates on the same document, one of the thread will back off and retry. Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/ for more information.

Comment: mongoose doesn't have any concept of transactions at all built in. Commits are atomic on the document level. What I want to know is
1. what happens if another thread reads documents as they are being updated by a query like this
2. what happens if two queries are trying to update an overlapping set of documents in this way

Comment: 1. As they are being updated, reads will wait (MMAPv1) or return the old version (WiredTiger). 2. If it concerns a single document, one of the updates will succeed, while the other will retry.

Comment: But the whole reason I'm asking this is that the query doesn't just concern a single document. If it did, the behaviour would be fairly obvious. What you''re saying seems to indicate to me that option 3 definitely won't happen, but still doesn't tell me whether or not option 2 can happen.
Does the query which checks and updates multiple documents lock them all, then update, or does it only lock them one at a time as it updates them? What happens when a second query tries to update a document that the first query hasn't gotten to yet?

Comment: MongoDB (and by association mongoose) is only atomic at the document level. If there are multiple documents involved then there's no atomicity guarantee.

Comment: I understand that, and have read as much in several places. That doesn't actually answer any of my questions though.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't answer your question. Let me put it this way: 1. MongoDB only has atomic guarantees for single document updates. 2. Mongoose is using MongoDB's node driver which doesn't attempt to provide multi-document atomicity guarantee. 3. Updating multiple documents can result in race condition and inconsistencies, but this can be overcome by simulating two-phase commit. Hence, multi-document atomicity is not guaranteed at the database level. However if you have a mechanism to simulate this, then it could work but it won't be a guarantee from the database itself.

Comment: If you still have unanswered questions, perhaps you can update your question with more examples so that it's clearer what you're asking about.

Comment: In my question above, I pretty clearly lay out a scenario, list some hypothetical outcomes, and ask which are possible. I just want to know which of them are possible. I am well aware that commits to MongoDB are atomic on the document level only, however I am not aware of the full implications of that, which is why I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: The simple answer is: definitely not #1, but #2 or #3 could be the result depending on the race condition induced on the driver, cache, etc. Both are wrong results judging from the intent, that it's academical to determine which is more wrong and which is less wrong. The point I'm trying to make is, perhaps you can tell us what your goal is, rather than having a discussion about which wrong result is more wrong than another.

Comment: I'm trying to implement something like a two phase commit and want to know where and how things can possibly go wrong. Scenario 3 is ***a lot*** worse than 2, because it means that there's a chance it could *look* like everything is okay when in reality a race condition has caused the transaction id of a bunch of inventory items to be overwritten by a different transaction. We will be able to tell something went wrong when trying to set the items' state to complete, but by that point payment will have already been processed.

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/ although note that the examples provided are simplified to explain the concept. I imagine a real production system will follow the pattern with more sanity checks.

Comment: The responses to someone else's question here seem to contradict you:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/nMUmIgXyrYg


According to the answer given in this link, scenario 3 can never happen, only scenario 2. If one query updates a document that the other query has not yet reached, the second query will not match that document and therefore will not update it.

Comment: That answer is from 2014, things might have changed in 4 years. I am saying that you should **not** depend on a race condition behaving in a certain manner to implement anything. By definition, race conditions are **unpredictable**. Scenarios 2 and 3 are the wrong thing to do with MongoDB, so expending more energy on the wrong thing is not productive in my opinion.

Comment: MongoDB (as at 3.6) does not provide query isolation or transactional multi-document updates. It is possible for multiple document writes to yield, so concurrent batch updates writing to the same documents introduce race conditions with undefined outcomes: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#read-uncommitted-and-multiple-document-write. Transaction-like semantics require additional application logic: two-phase commits or optimistic versioning. There are several Node libraries that implement transaction-like patterns (eg: Fawn, mongoose-transactions).